# Can Jssor slider skip bad/inaccessible image URLs. Is it even possible?

Tags: javascript, url, dynamic, slider, jssor

I would like to know if it is possible to setup Jssor slider to skip bad inaccessible URLs. I have a software that dynamically adds URLs, 1-12 pictures. The slider code I have is for 12 pictures total. Naturally, if only 11 pictures are used by this software, I have a blank thumbnail and image loading gif in the slider container. I would appreciate if you could point me in the right direction.

This is the code I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>Image Gallery Vertical Thumbnail Navigation Bar Theme - Jssor Slider, Slideshow with Javascript Source Code</title>
</head>
<body style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; font-family:Arial, Verdana;background-color:#fff;">
<!-- use jssor.slider.min.js instead for release -->
<!-- jssor.slider.min.js = (jssor.js + jssor.slider.js) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jssor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jssor.slider.js"></script>
<script>

    jssor_slider1_starter = function (containerId) {

        var _SlideshowTransitions = [
        //Zoom- in
        {$Duration: 1200, $Zoom: 0, $Easing: { $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad }, $Opacity: 2 },
        ];

        var options = {
            $FillMode: 1,
            $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
            $AutoPlayInterval: 1500,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
            $PauseOnHover: 1,                                //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, 4 freeze for desktop, 8 freeze for touch device, 12 freeze for desktop and touch device, default value is 1

            $DragOrientation: 3,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)
            $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                          //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
            $SlideDuration: 600,                                //Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds

            $SlideshowOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable slideshow or not
                $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,                 //[Required] Class to create instance of slideshow
                $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,            //[Required] An array of slideshow transitions to play slideshow
                $TransitionsOrder: 1,                           //[Optional] The way to choose transition to play slide, 1 Sequence, 0 Random
                $ShowLink: true                                    //[Optional] Whether to bring slide link on top of the slider when slideshow is running, default value is false
            },

            $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {                       //[Optional] Options to specify and enable arrow navigator or not
                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                $ChanceToShow: 1,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                $AutoCenter: 2,                                 //[Optional] Auto center navigator in parent container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                $Steps: 1                                       //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
            },

            $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {                       //[Optional] Options to specify and enable thumbnail navigator or not
                $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,              //[Required] Class to create thumbnail navigator instance
                $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always

                $ActionMode: 1,                                 //[Optional] 0 None, 1 act by click, 2 act by mouse hover, 3 both, default value is 1
                $Lanes: 2,                                      //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange thumbnails, default value is 1
                $SpacingX: 14,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each thumbnail in pixel, default value is 0
                $SpacingY: 12,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each thumbnail in pixel, default value is 0
                $DisplayPieces: 6,                             //[Optional] Number of pieces to display, default value is 1
                $ParkingPosition: 156,                          //[Optional] The offset position to park thumbnail
                $Orientation: 2                                //[Optional] Orientation to arrange thumbnails, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, default value is 1
            }
        };

        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(containerId, options);
        //responsive code begin
        //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
        function ScaleSlider() {
            var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
            if (parentWidth)
                jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.max(Math.min(parentWidth, 1040), 300));
            else
                $Jssor$.$Delay(ScaleSlider, 30);
        }

        ScaleSlider();
        $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "load", ScaleSlider);


        if (!navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|BlackBerry|IEMobile)/)) {
            $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "resize", $Jssor$.$WindowResizeFilter(window, ScaleSlider));
        }

        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad)/)) {
            $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
        }
        //responsive code end
    };
</script>
<!-- Jssor Slider Begin -->
<!-- You can move inline styles to css file or css block. -->
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1040px;
    height: 600px; background: #191919; overflow: hidden;">

    <!-- Loading Screen -->
    <div u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
        <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity:0.7; position: absolute; display: block;
            background-color: #000000; top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
        </div>
        <div style="position: absolute; display: block; background: url(../img/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;
            top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Slides Container -->
    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 800px; height: 600px; overflow: hidden;">
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="[[PictureURL1]]" />
    <div u="thumb">
            <div style="[[PictureURL1]]); background-position: center center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain;">
            </div>
    </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="[[PictureURL2]]" />
    <div u="thumb">
            <div style="[[PictureURL2]]); background-position: center center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain;">
            </div>
    </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="[[PictureURL3]]" />
    <div u="thumb">
            <div style="[[PictureURL3]]); background-position: center center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain;">
            </div>
    </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="[[PictureURL4]]" />
    <div u="thumb">
            <div style="[[PictureURL4]]); background-position: center center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain;">
            </div>
    </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="[[PictureURL5]]" />
    <div u="thumb">
            <div style="[[PictureURL5]]); background-position: center center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain;">
            </div>
    </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="[[PictureURL6]]" />
    <div u="thumb">
            <div style="[[PictureURL6]]); background-position: center center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain;">
            </div>
    </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="[[PictureURL7]]" />
    <div u="thumb">
            <div style="[[PictureURL7]]); background-position: center center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain;">
            </div>
    </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="[[PictureURL8]]" />
    <div u="thumb">
            <div style="[[PictureURL8]]); background-position: center center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain;">
            </div>
    </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="[[PictureURL9]]" />
    <div u="thumb">
            <div style="[[PictureURL9]]); background-position: center center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain;">
            </div>
    </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="[[PictureURL10]]" />
    <div u="thumb">
            <div style="[[PictureURL10]]); background-position: center center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain;">
            </div>
    </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="[[PictureURL11]]" />
    <div u="thumb">
            <div style="[[PictureURL11]]); background-position: center center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain;">
            </div>
    </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="[[PictureURL12]]" />
    <div u="thumb">
            <div style="[[PictureURL12]]); background-position: center center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain;">
            </div>
    </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin Begin -->
    <style>
        /* jssor slider arrow navigator skin 05 css */
        /*
        .jssora05l              (normal)
        .jssora05r              (normal)
        .jssora05l:hover        (normal mouseover)
        .jssora05r:hover        (normal mouseover)
        .jssora05ldn            (mousedown)
        .jssora05rdn            (mousedown)
        */
        .jssora05l, .jssora05r, .jssora05ldn, .jssora05rdn
        {
            position: absolute;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: block;
            background: url(../img/a17.png) no-repeat;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
        .jssora05l { background-position: -10px -40px; }
        .jssora05r { background-position: -70px -40px; }
        .jssora05l:hover { background-position: -130px -40px; }
        .jssora05r:hover { background-position: -190px -40px; }
        .jssora05ldn { background-position: -250px -40px; }
        .jssora05rdn { background-position: -310px -40px; }
    </style>
    <!-- Arrow Left -->
    <span u="arrowleft" class="jssora05l" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; top: 158px; left: 8px;">
    </span>
    <!-- Arrow Right -->
    <span u="arrowright" class="jssora05r" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; top: 158px; right: 248px">
    </span>
    <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin End -->

    <!-- Thumbnail Navigator Skin 02 Begin -->
    <div u="thumbnavigator" class="jssort02" style="position: absolute; width: 240px; height: 600px; left:800px; bottom: 0px;">

        <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin Begin -->
        <style>
            /* jssor slider thumbnail navigator skin 02 css */
            /*
            .jssort02 .p            (normal)
            .jssort02 .p:hover      (normal mouseover)
            .jssort02 .pav          (active)
            .jssort02 .pav:hover    (active mouseover)
            .jssort02 .pdn          (mousedown)
            */
            .jssort02 .w
            {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
            .jssort02 .c
            {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                width: 95px;
                height: 62px;
                border: #000 2px solid;
            }
            .jssort02 .p:hover .c, .jssort02 .pav:hover .c, .jssort02 .pav .c 
            {
                background: url(../img/t01.png) center center;
                border-width: 0px;
                top: 2px;
                left: 2px;
                width: 95px;
                height: 62px;
            }
            .jssort02 .p:hover .c, .jssort02 .pav:hover .c
            {
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                width: 97px;
                height: 64px;
                border: #fff 1px solid;
            }
        </style>
        <div u="slides" style="cursor: move;">
            <div u="prototype" class="p" style="position: absolute; width: 99px; height: 66px; top: 0; left: 0;">
                <div class=w><thumbnailtemplate style=" width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none;position:absolute; top: 0; left: 0;"></thumbnailtemplate></div>
                <div class=c>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin End -->
    </div>
    <!-- Thumbnail Navigator Skin End -->
    <a style="display: none" href="http://www.jssor.com">javascript</a>
    <!-- Trigger -->
    <script>
        jssor_slider1_starter('slider1_container');
    </script>
</div>
<!-- Jssor Slider End -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove slides with invalid picture url before initialization of Jssor Slider.

```
//remove invalid slides
var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(...
```

Or rou can keep slides html code empty, and fill slides html code dynamically before initialization of Jssor Slider.

```
//fill slides html code
var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(...
```